# Why is my code not working when t is similar to MDN? (OOP)

Tags: javascript, oop

This is MDN's ball velocity code:

```
var ball = {
  x: 100,
  y: 100,
  vx: 5,
  vy: 2,
  radius: 25,
  color: 'blue',
  draw: function() {
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(this.x, this.y, this.radius, 0, Math.PI*2, true);
    ctx.closePath();
    ctx.fillStyle = this.color;
    ctx.fill();
  }
};

function draw() {
  ctx.clearRect(0,0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  ball.draw();
  ball.x += ball.vx;
  ball.y += ball.vy;
  raf = window.requestAnimationFrame(draw);
};

canvas.addEventListener('mouseover', function(e){
  raf = window.requestAnimationFrame(draw);
});

ball.draw();
```

My code is here:

```
var Ball = function(x, y, vx, vy, r, color) {
  this.x = x;
  this.y = y;
  this.vx = vx;
  this.vy = vy;
  this.radius = r;
  this.color = color;
  this.draw = function() {
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(x, y, r, 0, Math.PI * 2, true);
    ctx.closePath();
    ctx.fillStyle = color;
    ctx.fill();
  }
};

function movement() {
  pingPong.draw();
  pingPong.x += pingPong.vx;
  pingPong.y += pingPong.vy;
  raf = window.requestAnimationFrame(movement);
};

canvas.addEventListener('mouseover', function(e){
  raf = window.requestAnimationFrame(movement);
});

var pingPong = new Ball(100, 100, 5, 1, 15, 'black');

pingPong.draw();
```

I can't understand why my ball isn't being redrawn.  To me they look exactly the same and I have console.log'd my x and y coordinates and they are updating as they should be.  Can anyone tell me why mine isn't working?

Comment: What errors do you get in the web console? What do you see when you step through the code with the powerful debugger built into your browser?

Comment: pingPong.ball() is not anything

Comment: also: ctx.arc(x, y, r, 0, Math.PI * 2, true); is wrong, it should be ctx.arc(this.x, this.y, this.r, 0, Math.PI *2, true);

Comment: I'm sorry for not clarifying/putting in my whole code.  raf is declared as a global.  When I replace my code with MDN's code the ball moves.  When I step through the code with debugger I see that x and y values are being updated every time that movement is called in the window.requestAnimationFrame(movement); and that it is calling the movement function.


Thanks for noticing that Deamedeor, but code actually has pingPong.draw() and I have updated the original post to reflect that.

Comment: @TheMinister - Thank you!  This works!  I still don't understand what you mean by instance and the constructor params, but I will look into it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MDN's

```
ctx.arc(this.x, this.y, this.radius, 0, Math.PI*2, true);
ctx.closePath();
ctx.fillStyle = this.color;
```

Yours

```
ctx.arc(x, y, r, 0, Math.PI * 2, true);
ctx.closePath();
ctx.fillStyle = color;
```

In your code, you didn't prepend with `this.` which might make your object doesn't have color and placed out of screen.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder it would take the inital values passed in and draw on top of that. it would work but it wouldn't update

Comment: @ardhitama - My understanding is that since I have "this.color = color" I can just use "ctx.fillStyle = color".  My ball gets drawn, but just doesn't move.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder according to the question "my ball isn't being redrawn" so he's seeing something.. just not being rerendered :P so ardhitama is right

Comment: A jsFiddle which also includes clearing the canvas https://jsfiddle.net/yezf68y5/1/

Comment: Your solution works @TheMinister.  Thank you very much!